# How to do performance testing of RabbitMQ Cluster to do further fine tuning?

Tags: rabbitmq, performance-testing

I have created a RabbitMQ Cluster which is successfully queuing messages being generated by application. I need to do performance testing of the cluster to find out overall efficiency of the cluster and take decisions to do further fine tuning to enhance performance. We tried with `PerfTest` java tool. But could not achieve much.

Comment: You should elaborate more on what's exact problem you having. Also what do you mean by `could not achieve much`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the questions begin with which interface are you looking to test?  That will decide your tool(s) which support that interface.

Are you looking to both push and pop?

How many queues?

How many producers and how many consumers?  Will you create a slight vacuum with the consumers to affect an always or nearly empty queue set?

How will you define efficiency?   Is this defined by the number of items in the queue, the time to push or pop from the queue or some combination of the the previous?

???